# The declared package "java.lang" doesn't match the expected package ""

Tags: java

I am trying to use Comparable Interface in Eclipse, but I keep getting the above error, I am not able to import `package java.lang;`

Comment: You cannot import it. It is already imported, by default.

Comment: You cannot import packages, you import classes. For all, import package.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's either :

```
import java.lang.*;
```

Or

```
import java.lang.Comparable;
```

but not :

```
import java.lang;
```

Because it's a syntax error in Java.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi It is a package -- it *contains* classes. The problem is *not* that it has already been imported.

Comment: @JonathanLam I am saying that `import package java.lang.*;` is invalid.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi Oh yeah. But it's been fixed now.

Comment: My bad. I did it too fast

Comment: @MickaëlB I am saying that my downvote has been "fixed".